# Proof in The Integral Test

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> **Theorem**: Assume there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $f:[N,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is non-negative, continuous and decreasing. Define $a_n=f(n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$. Then, $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if and only if $\int_{N}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ converges.

**Proof**: Since $f$ is decreasing, we find that
$$
a_{n+1}=f(n+1)\leq \int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\leq f(n)=a_n
$$
for all $n\geq N$. Defining $b_n=\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ for $n\geq N$, it follows from the Comparison Test that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_n$ converges.

> **Question**: Is $$
> \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_n \textrm{ converges}\implies \int_{N}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx \textrm{ converges}?
> $$

I am asking this, because of the definition
$$ 
\int_{N}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx:=\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{N}^{A}f(x)\,dx
$$
where $A$ is a real number.

**Edit**: Found something in [LINK](http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/footer/Courses/M111-112/Handouts/SERIES1.PDF), on the last page, in particular Lemma 3. Note that
$$
\sum_{n=N}^{M}b_n=\int_{N}^{M+1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
for all integers $M\geq N$. So, if $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_n$ converges,  the partial sums of it is bounded above by some positive number $K$. Therefore $\int_{N}^{M+1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x<K$ for all $M\geq N$. I am wondering, if this implies $\int_{N}^{A+1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x<K$ for all real numbers $A\geq N$ ...

Comment: The equality in the edit should be an inequality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1)** For your second question in the edit: suppose there is a real number $A \geq N$ such that
$$
  \int_N^{A+1} f(x)\, dx \geq K.
$$ 
Since $f$ is non-negative, the integral of $f$ from $A+1$ to $\lceil A+1 \rceil$ is non-negative as well. Therefore
$$
 \int_N^{\lceil A+1\rceil} f(x)\, dx  =  \int_N^{A+1} f(x)\, dx  +  \int_{A+1}^{\lceil A+1\rceil} f(x)\, dx  \geq K + \int_{A+1}^{\lceil A+1\rceil} f(x)\, dx \geq K.
$$
But since $\lceil A+1 \rceil$ is a natural number, we have a contradiction.

**(2)** Now let's prove your original question. Assume the series converges to $L$. The argument in paragraph (1) shows that $L- \int_N^{x+1}f(x)\,dx \geq 0$ for every real $x$.  Take $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary. Since the series converges, there is a natural number $M \geq N$ such that 
$$
  L - \int_N^{M+1} f(x)\,dx = L-  \sum_{n=N}^M b_n < \epsilon.
$$
Note that the function $\int_N^{x+1} f(x)\,dx$ is increasing since $f$ is non-negative. Therefore we have for every $x\geq M$ that
$$
 L - \int_N^{x+1} f(x)\,dx \leq  L - \int_N^{M+1} f(x)\,dx < \epsilon.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please show me how my original question follows from Lemma 2? Nice with proof by contradiction ...

Comment: You're welcome. I have added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time ... I have thought similar to it. I will explain why I didn't follow this path. Lemma 2 tells us that if $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, let us call the limit $L$, then $\lim_{m\to\infty}c_m=L$. This shows that if $\int_{N}^{\infty}f(x)\ dx$ converges, then $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_n$ converges. That's the way I understand it. What I actually needed is to show the converse direction. That's why I picked Lemma 3, and then I would conclude by using Lemma 2. Unfortunately, I am stuck at "proving" if $g$ is in fact increasing before I could use Lemma 3.

Comment: I see the problem. I assumed Lemma 2 was an equivalence, but it is indeed formulated as a one direction implication. I've adjusted my question, without using any result of the link.