# $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(k) = \int\limits_1^n f(x)\mathrm{d}x + O(?)$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, estimation

It is well know trivial to find an upper or lower bound for a sum by estimating it as an integral, for example
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(k) \leq \int\limits_1^n f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
if $f$ is monotone increasing. However, I wonder if its possible to determine the error term we put up with this estimation. I suspect it should be something like
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(k) = \int\limits_1^n f(x)\mathrm{d}x + O(f(n))$$
but I am unable to proof this rigerously by definition of Big-O.

I would appreciate any help or hints on this.

Comment: See this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2996978/121671)

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_remainder_term).